# Different syntax on mongodb module in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm now learning how to use MongoDB in Node.js, but as long as I know, there are two ways to write the code.

One (on some books and online blogs):

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db, Connection = require('mongodb').Connection, Server = require('mongodb').Server;
```

Two (Github page and its documentation page on 10gen):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

Why does the disparity occur and which one should I take if there are any differences other than syntax? Perhaps it's due to different versions of the module, but if so on what number I have to take one over the other?

Thanks.

Comment: `MongoClient` is a recent addition to all the drivers and is now the generally preferred way to go.

Comment: If it's recommended by 10gen, you shouldn't consider another option :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MongoClient` is the new prefered way for **all** the different drivers. It has acknowledged (safe) writes on by default and should be the general interface to MongoDB. See http://blog.mongodb.org/post/36666163412/introducing-mongoclient for more information about how and why.